# memory footprint section in c

Tags: c, memory

could you explain what these section mean when you collect memory footprint in c?
I can see .text is source code and I assume .const and .data are global data and constants(but not too sure) and what does .bss mean?

```
| .text    | .const    | .data     | .bss      |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.bss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) is/are uninitialised `static` variables.

```
// foo ends up in bss (because it is not explicitly initialised)
// it's initial value is whatever the default 'zero' value for the type is.
static int foo;
// bar ends up in .data
// (because) it is initialised with the value 42. 
static int bar = 42;
// baz ends up in .const
// (because) it is initialised with a value (22) and the object is const.
// meaning that the value cannot be allowed to change, meaning the object
// can be safely mapped to read-only memory pages (if supported).
static const int baz = 22;
// code goes in .text:
int main() { return 0; }
```

Comment: then is .const just constant and .data is global variables?

Comment: @CBK added code sample with comments to explain how this works.

Comment: It's not just for `static` variables, though. It's for all zero-initialized variables, `static` or not.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Not zero-initialized variables with automatic storage duration!

Answer (score 1):

Some answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312929/beginners-confusion-about-x86-stack/30313437#30313437). That covers also the run-time managed sections *heap* and *stack* (that was the original answer).

In short (an extended):

- `.bss` is for uninitialized variables declared `static` and with global scope. This is not actually stored in the file, but just reserved and cleared at run-time right before `main() is called.
- `.data` contains explicitly initialized variables.
- `.const` contains `const` declared objects.
- `.text` is where the program code is stored. Note that is *not* the source code, but the compiled program code!

There is also a plethora of other sections in normal "ELF" object files which contain debugging information, etc.

For more information, read about object file formats. One of the most widely used is [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

Answer (score 0):

`bss`(`Block Started by Symbol`) stores the zero-value initialised static-allocated variables (including `global` and `static` variables). If the initialised value of a static-allocated is not `0`, e.g.:

```
int global = 5;
```

Then the `global` will be allocated in `data` section.